# Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent

Tags: login, errors, headers

I've checked the offical "[How do I solve the Headers already sent warning problem?](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F)" and have resolved a whitespace problem, changing:

`function mhm_footerheader_position ()`

to

`function mhm_footerheader_position()`, but at /wp-login.php, we still receive the error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/username/public_html/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/mhm-functions.php:281)
>   in /home/username/public_html/wp-login.php on line 394

Here is mhm-functions.php from line 280:

```
function mhm_footerheader_position() {
    echo '<div id="footer-header"><div class="wrap">';
    genesis_widget_area('footer-header');
    echo '</div></div>';
}

add_action ('widgets_init','mhm_footerheader_position');
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure there is a plugin, function or php file adding space or characters before the header. This happened to me too. Some will add hidden characters that you can't see without a text editor that can show all characters. Try disabling every plugin and them enable them 1 by 1 to see which one is causing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you misunderstood ["How do I solve the Headers already sent warning problem?"](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F)

As you said, you've changed:

```
function mhm_footerheader_position ()
```

to:

```
function mhm_footerheader_position()
```

The only difference I see is the `space` between `mhm_footerheader_position` and `()`. The whitespace problem in `header already sent error`, isn't about the space between `function_name` and `()`. It's about `space` that gets into the output before any HTTP header is sent.

Secondly, you don't want to output anything in [`widgets_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widgets_init/) action, this the the wrong place for any output. The error you are getting is because you are giving output in `widgets_init` action and in `wp-login.php` HTTP header is being sent after this action hook.

I can't say exactly where you want to output the `footer-header` widget area, it depends on your theme. However, the following CODE will output it in the footer and solve your Error:

```
    function mhm_footerheader_position () {
        echo '<div id="footer-header"><div class="wrap">';
        genesis_widget_area('footer-header');
        echo '</div></div>';
    }

    add_action ('wp_footer','mhm_footerheader_position');
```

You may read [this to understand the Hearer Already Send Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) better.